# VBscript fails when calling jquery in testcomplete

Tags: jquery, vbscript, testcomplete

This occurs in testcomplete version 9.20, and test against firefox 19.0.2.

First script file is called `test` and it contains the following lines:

```
'USEUNIT CommonFunctions
Public Function test()
  Call expandTree()
End Function
```

The other script file is named `CommonFunctions` has this function:

```
Public Function expandTree()
  Set foo = Aliases.tree.contentDocument.Script.jQuery("li[data-nodeid='sites'] a.openClose").click()
End Function
```

When I run the script the automation files giving the following error:

```
Microsoft VBscript runtime error.

Object doesn't support this property or method:"contentDocument.Script.jQuery(...).Click''

Error location:
Unit:"ContentSuite\Content\Script\CommonFunctions"
Line:3972 Coloumn2
```

The same error will not occur if I place the jquery in the same file. That is if I run this it will work properly, and the click would work fine:

```
Public Function test()
  Set foo = Aliases.tree.contentDocument.Script.jQuery("li[data-nodeid='sites'] a.openClose").click()
End Function
```

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your full code. Could you please edit your question and include the code of both functions?

Comment: added more details, thanks for the comment

Comment: Still not enough information. Please tell us which version of TestComplete and which exactly browser you use. Also, please check whether the expandTree routine can be executed if you run it directly from the CommonFunctions unit.

Comment: I am using testcomplete version 9.20, and i tried this against firefox  19.0.2. It works fine if the expand routine is called directly from the common function unit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your current code uses the DOM `click` method, which does not have a return value, so you need to remove `Set foo =`.

The error might be that the jQuery selector did not find any matching objects. Try checking the `length` property of the `jQuery` function result:

```
Set links = Aliases.tree.contentDocument.Script.jQuery("li[data-nodeid='sites'] a.openClose")
If links.length > 0 Then
  links.click
Else
  Log.Error "Object not found."
End If
```

But actually there's no need to use jQuery here, since TestComplete has the built-in [`QuerySelector`](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/42163/) method:

```
Set obj = Aliases.tree.QuerySelector("li[data-nodeid='sites'] a.openClose")
If Not obj Is Nothing Then
  obj.Click
Else
  Log.Error "Object not found."
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the help helen! now it works correctly and without any problem

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem can be related to the fact that you are trying to call the **click** method of an object returned by the **jQuery** method. Since this method returns a collection, try getting a specific object before clicking it:

```
Public Function expandTree()
  Aliases.tree.contentDocument.Script.jQuery("li[data-nodeid='sites'] a.openClose").get(0).click()
End Function
```